# get input from reusuable field in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i have created reusable text field and button, and i am simply calling them whenever i want to use any.
for example
in my login page I am calling

```
          InputBox(Text:'Username'),
          SizedBox(height: 40,),
          InputBox(Text:'Password'),
          SizedBox(height: 40,),
          AuthButton(text:'Sign In'),
```

and similarly on the registeration page :

```
              InputBox(Text:'Name'),
              SizedBox(height: 40,),
              InputBox(Text:'Username'),
              SizedBox(height: 40,),
              InputBox(Text:'Password'),
              SizedBox(height: 40,),
              AuthButton(text:'Sign up'),
```

to create a simple login form so that i can reuse this in my registeration page aswell.
i have created a model fi;e, where all the models for textfielf and button are stored.
the model is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class InputBox extends StatelessWidget {
  String Text;
  InputBox({this.Text});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10,2,10,2),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.red)
      ),
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none,
          labelText: Text,
        ),
        onChanged: (v){
         print("hello");
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AuthButton extends StatelessWidget {
  String text;
  AuthButton({this.text});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10,2,10,2),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.red)
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16,vertical: 8),
        child: Text(text,style: TextStyle(color:Colors.red,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold ),),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

but now I want to take input from both login and registration page, and i tried everything that i could, to have the result on their respective pages(login details on login page, and registrations details on registration page).
any idea how to do that.
thanks in advance

Comment: You need to pass controller for your textfield which will return your entered data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 TextEditingController emailController = new TextEditingController();
 TextEditingController passwordController = new TextEditingController();

            InputBox(
              Text: "Email",
              textEditingController: emailController,
            ),
            InputBox(
              Text: "Password",
              textEditingController: passwordController,
            ),
```

Now you can call Textfield value on the event of onTab or onpress like this

```
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print("Email:${emailController.text}"); 
                print("Password:${passwordController.text}");
              },
              color: Colors.red,
              splashColor: Colors.white,
              elevation: 2,
              child: Text(
                "buttonName",
              ),
            )
```

---

```
class InputBox extends StatelessWidget {

String Text;

TextEditingController textEditingController;
InputBox({this.Text, this.textEditingController});
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 2, 10, 2),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
      border: Border.all(color: Colors.red)),
  child: TextField(
    controller: textEditingController,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: InputBorder.none,
      labelText: Text,
    ),
    onChanged: (v) {
      print("On change <ethod:${textEditingController.text}");
     },
   ),
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: hi @Shubham, thanks for your reply, i just applied your code, and it worked fine, as i am new to flutter, i wanted to know, on clicking the button, sign in or signup, it should print whatever was entered. how can we do that? thanks

Comment: @ankitkumar  print("Email:${emailController.text}"); print("Password:${passwordController.text}");

you can add this two lines on your onpress of button 

please check code again

Comment: @ankitkumar you can check my answer again

Comment: thank you @Shubham, so the button cant be fully reusable, thanks for your time once again your code worked perfectly fine for me. still i was curious to know , that in this scenario, importing full button from a different model file is not possible? am i correct?

Comment: Means you want reusable button ? @ankitkumar

Comment: as in my question above i am importing AuthButton. this means the design should be same for all the buttons whenever i import, and only onclick or onpressed should be different, is that possible?

Comment: Yes @ankitkumar possible

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextEditingController`. Initiate `TextEditingController` on your parent component, and give as input parameter for your `InputBox` widget.

```
class InputBox extends StatelessWidget {
  String Text;
  TextEditingController controller; // initiate as a input property.
  InputBox({this.Text, this.controller});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10,2,10,2),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.red)
      ),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: controller, //add controller to text field.
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none,
          labelText: Text,
        ),
        onChanged: (v){
         print("hello");
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And on your parent widget your can define a variable like this.

```
final _inputCtrl = TextEditingController();

...
Container(chlid:InputBox(controller:_inputCtrl, text:'hello')
```

You can get the value entered in the input box using `_inputCtrl.value.text` getter.